# Tenability of solution to synchronous XMLHttpRequest deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This problem has been reported on many forums, including this one, and I've found a solution that is apparently unique, although I'm not sure if it's wise. It certainly does work, but it's probably something someone closer to the JQuery development or one of its members might be able to answer with authority.

The issue that many others and I have experienced is a console error message with this text:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

In my case, and in the cases of many others, it references the jquery.js file, specifically this line

```
xhr.open( options.type, options.url, options.async; options.username, options.password );
```

The relevant information at http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ states:

> Developers must not pass false for the async argument when the
>   JavaScript global environment is a document environment.

I have many complex, minified routines written by others that make use of JQuery, and I'm no expert at finding *where* in those routines the error would be created.

It then hit me to simply substitute `true` for `options.async` in the jquery.js file, like this:

```
xhr.open( options.type, options.url, true, options.username, options.password );
```

Voila! The problem vanished on every browser where the console reported an error. (Locating and editing the correlative code in the minified JQuery.min.js file was a snap; finding it in all of the other routines that depend on JQuery would have been tedious if not mildly impossible.)

But my question is this: Is this apparent hack of a solution unwise? My site *does* work, and none of the routines that make use of JQuery has a problem with this. Commentary much appreciated.

Comment: It's a hack in the sense that it will break code which relies on the AJAX call being made synchronously (which no one should be doing because it's incredibly bad practice). If you have 100% control of the code on your site then I would say you could get away with it, but beware that it could lead to odd behaviour in some cases. If you are relying on code which uses `async: false`, I would suggest you fire the dev that wrote the code originally, then re-write it.

Comment: seems like you are just kicking the can down the road and opening yourself to future headaches ... use `find/replace` in your IDE and if you don't have one their are numerous free ones that will do it

Comment: _"have many complex, minified routines written by others that make use of JQuery, and I'm no expert at finding where in those routines the error would be created"_ Use `$.ajaxSetup()` to define check at `beforeSend` function , `if (settings.options.async === "false") {debugger}` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If you read the spec, passing `false` was supported by this function in the past, but it's now considered deprecated and will be phased out, thus the strict warning message. No one should be fired. @charlietfl It's more complex than a simple search-and-replace as this function is called from within another, etc. @guest271314 Thanks for that debugging technique suggesion...I'll put it to use. Curiously, this error first appeared in my consoles when running my code in Bitnami Wamp & Php7 RC6...not true when run in XAMPP and Php5.6

Comment: @Tom Don't worry it was a light hearted comment. `async: false` was always a fully legitimate thing to do, but terrible in practice - similar to `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

**THE PROBLEM IS IN THE JQUERY DISTRIBUTABLE ITSELF**

The cause of the problem is in the jquery.js file as found in the current version 2.1.4. Despite documenting `options.async` as a deprecated parameter that should only be passed a value of `true`, the jquery.js file itself calls the xhr.open file using data defined earlier in the file with the parameter set to `false`. This is the offending routine in the jquery.js file:

```
jQuery._evalUrl = function( url ) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,
        global: false,
        "throws": true
    });
};
```

When `async` is set to `true`, the problem vanishes, and the hack solution I had previously used is no longer needed.

Now, seriously, this is something a true JQuery expert should comment on. Why would the JQuery initialization file violate the very standard of usage that it advises its users to follow?

Comment: There is a jQuery forum, ask there... Ranting on stackoverflow is not getting you anywhere. Or file a bug with the jQuery core.

Comment: IIRC, they do `evalUrl` when writing HTML and want synchronous evaluation of scripts therein.

Comment: @espascarello It's not a rant against JQuery until you discover it's a bug in their own initialization file; for the countless others who have reported this problem here and elsewhere, I've supplied a solution via this post. (And I'm now reporting it on the JQuery bug list.)